# Angular Observable

Tags: angular, observable

How do I change the value in the Observable which is in the service using only the method through the method getUserInfo()?

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {

    public User: UserInfo = {
        firstName: "O",
        lastName: "K",
        email: "ol@op.com",
        country: "uk",
        avatarUrl: null,
        receiveNotifications: true
    }
    private Obser: Observable<UserInfo> = new Observable(observer => {
        observer.next(this.User);

    });
    getUserInfo(): Observable<UserInfo> {
        return this.Obser;
    }
}
```

use service :

```js
openDialog() {
    let subscription = this.UserService.getUserInfo().subscribe(data =>( data=this.data));
    //What should I write here to change the value inside the observable? Please write if it is not difficult
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change already emitted data. You can emit data again.

I think you need something like this (I didn't test that, just an idea):

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    userData$: Observable < any > ;

    constructor() {
        this.userData$ = new BehaviorSubject();
    }

    getUserInfoObservable() {
        return this.userData.asObservable();
    }

    updateUserInfo(newData) {
        this.userData.next(newData);
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
    myData: any;
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        myService.getUserInfoObservable().subscribe((newData) => this.myData = newData;
    }
}
```

When you want to update data you will use `myService.updateUserInfo(newData)`.

You need BehaviourSubject because you of course want get current user data immediately. What if you component is lazy loaded? You want to get *current* data and all new data in it.

You also can set initial value of BehaviorSubject by `new BehaviorSubject(null)`. Null is initial value there.

BehaviorSubject is part of beautiful rxjs lib. Full docs is available, for example, [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md).

Comment: I tried to explain everything verbose. If you have any questions you are welcome.

Comment: You should use the `asObservable()` on the Subject in order to return an observable for it.

Comment: Do you mean this? `return this.userData.toObservable()`? Where I can read about it? I found only [this](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/notification/notification_instance_methods/toobservable.html)

Comment: `return this.userData.asObservable()`, technically the code you wrote will work since BehaviorSubject inherit from Observable.
The only problem with it is it allow who get the `BehaviorSubject` with the `getUserInfoObservable` function to emit new data through it, passing potentially any additional logic you might have in `updateUserInfo`. [link](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/asobservable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Once emitted with `next()`, the value can not be changed. According to the concept of reactive programming, it is better to call `next()` again with the changed value.

Comment: `but how can I call next() again here : openDialog() {

      let subscription = this.UserService.getUserInfo().
      subscribe(data =>( data=this.data))://What should I write here to change the value inside the observable? Please write if it is not difficult
  } ?`

Answer (score 0):

The `Observable` as its name suggest is an object that can be "observed" for event of new data, or in other words "subscribe" to event of new data emitted. What emit the data is not the Observable but it is the `observer` who observe for new data  and emit it using the `next` function.

Observable - an object to subscribe to for getting new data.
Observer - an object to publish new data.

```js
let observable: Observable<string> = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next('Hello'); // the observer emit the data
});

observable.subscribe((data) => { // You subscribe to the observable for new data
    console.log(data); // Print 'Hello'
});
```

If you want to be able to emit new data to all the subscribers who subscribed to this observable you need to use its observer:

```js
let observer;
let observable: Observable<string> = new Observable(o => {
    observer = o;
    observer.next('Hello'); // the observer emit the data
});

observable.subscribe((data) => { // You subscribe to the observable for new data
    console.log(data); // Print 'Hello World!
});

observer.next('World!');
```

Notice if you use the observable to make sure that all components are updated with the user information when it is updated I would add an update method to the service that allow emitting the new value.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {

    public user: UserInfo = {
        firstName: "O",
        lastName: "K",
        email: "ol@op.com",
        country: "uk",
        avatarUrl: null,
        receiveNotifications: true
    }
    private observer;
    private observable: Observable<UserInfo>;

    constructor () {
        this.observable = new Observable(o => {
            this.observer = o;
            this.observer.next(user);
        });
    }

    getUserInfo(): Observable<UserInfo> {
        return this.observable;
    }

    updateUserInfo(user: UserInfo) {
        this.user = user;
        this.observer.next(this.user);
    }
}
```

Now, in your dialog component you can use the `getUserInfo` function from the service to get an observable you can subscribe to in order to get user information. and use the `updateUserInfo` in order to update it.